# Flash Video Player: Transition control placement

Tags: flash, apache-flex, video

I'm customizing a video player (http://23video.com), and I'd like the controls to transition off screen after the mouse is stationary or outside of the player. At the moment, they instantly pop off screen. Here's the function that moves the controls:

```
private function trayHide():void {
    if (showPlayList) return;
    trayTimer.stop();
    if(props.getNumber('trayTimeout')<=0) return;
    tray.y = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height - 74;
    tray.visible = true;
}
```

Is there something I can put in place of the "tray.y = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height - 74;" to get it to transition the height change over a second or two?

PS: The video player that I'm basing this off of is at https://github.com/23/videoplayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First, I wrote the code for the 23 Video player; and would like to apologize for the confusion of the `tray.y` line. It's a weird kind of hard-code.)

You can achieve the animation through [mx.effects.Move](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/effects/Move.html)

Add this somewhere in the code:

```
import mx.effects.Move;
```

And this somewhere else:

```
<mx:Move id="moveEffect" target="{tray}" duration="500" />
```

With these in place you can substitute the `tray.y` line for:

```
moveEffect.end();
moveEffect.yTo = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height - 74;
moveEffect.play();
```

In addition to this simple trick, you will need to have placed the tray correctly beforehand; and to make sure it's visible while being animated.